# How to click on download icon on chrome browser using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download files by clicking on Download icon on **Chrome** browser.
I tried several ways like Xpath and CSS but it doesn't worked. Please let me know if there is any solution on this using Python 3.x and selenium.

Below is code that I have tried,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

class TEAutomation:

    def automateTask(self):
        chromeOptions = Options()
        chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",{"download.default_directory": "/home/vishal/Documents/PythonProgram/"})

        baseUrl = "https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer+Drawing%7F160743%7FM2%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_160743_M2.pdf%7F160743-1"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/vishal/PycharmProjects/VSProgramming/drivers/chromedriver",chrome_options=chromeOptions)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(baseUrl)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="download"]').click()
        #driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#download').click()

        time.sleep(5)
        driver.quit()

molexAuto = TEAutomation()
molexAuto.automateTask()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="download"]').click()` isn't it like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the element is still not loaded when you try to click it, try waiting for it with `WebDriverWait`, I don't have chrome so you will have to test this yourself:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

class TEAutomation:

    def automateTask(self):
        chromeOptions = Options()
        prefs = {
            "download.default_directory": "/home/vishal/Documents/PythonProgram/",
            "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
        }
        chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        baseUrl = "https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer+Drawing%7F160743%7FM2%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_160743_M2.pdf%7F160743-1"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/vishal/PycharmProjects/VSProgramming/drivers/chromedriver",chrome_options=chromeOptions)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get(baseUrl)

        time.sleep(5)
        driver.quit()

molexAuto = TEAutomation()
molexAuto.automateTask()
```

Comment: Hello Dalvenjia, I have tested your solution it didn't worked, it is giving error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Actually the download icon on page is getting hidden, mouse cursor need to be place there so the icon becomes visible on chrome

Comment: Oh boy, I think we have a bad case of the XY problem, you are actually trying do download a pdf over chrome's built-in pdf viewer. I have a better solution for you, just download the url, you can use the `requests` module in python or even `curl` on the command line

Comment: I also edited my answer to disable the built-in pdf viewer, just in case you still want to use `selenium` although I highly recommend that you go with the `requests` solution

Comment: Thank you Dalvenjia for your solution, I will use requests for this. I just want to know how the above code is automatically downloading file without using any click event.

Comment: Because `baseUrl` is pointing directly at a PDF download and since we instructed chrome to not open the pdf with the built-in viewer it just downloads it